# How to dump gitea repository remotely

Tags: git, gitea

I would like to use the `dump` command from the gitea docs.

See:
https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/backup-and-restore/

The reason I ask is because I naively installed gitea on a raspberry pi with not much storage, and it is reaching the point where I need to upgrade the storage for the repository's sake.

I would like to perform this command remotely and save the resulting zip file remotely because, naturally, the gitea database is so full that I don't think it would be able to dump locally before all remaining storage space is used.

How can I perform this command remotely and save the resulting .zip file remotely?

```
./gitea dump -c /path/to/app.ini
```

EDIT: It just occurred to me that I could dump to a flash drive too. I am open to any option but I need a hand with figuring out how to modify the above command to dump in the right spot.

Comment: I found the `dump` command in the source files. See: https://github.com/go-gitea/gitea/blob/master/cmd/dump.go

Comment: I am not familiar with `go` but I think adding the `-t` flag and specifying an additional directory will dump to a different path. I will test this later today and report what worked.

Comment: I have provided an answer for how to accomplish this with a USB drive but I will accept a future answer that provides a remote solution (e.g., via local network and ssh).

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution by using a local USB and digging into the source code.

```
# login as your database user, for me it is root
su -

# navigate to your gitea folder
cd /home/USER/gitea

# run the dump command
./gitea-1.9-whatever-this-is-my-relevant-app-file dump -t /media/USER/drive/
```

Note that, at least in Gitea 1.9, there is no need to use `-c /path/to/app.ini` as it is set to the correct directory by default. The `-t` flag will point the dump to the directory you want. In my case, a USB drive.

Comment: If you have a lot of files like me, might be helpful to throw-in `-V` so you can watch the dump

Comment: For verbose to work, place it before the `-t` flag and ensure that it is capitalized. For example: `./gitea-1.9-whatever-this-is-my-relevant-app-file dump -V -t /media/USER/drive/`